# Print n lines before match1 AND the lines after match1 until match2

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, grep

I know how to use grep -B n -A m match to print n and m lines before and after a match. I also know how to use sed to print from match1 until match2. But how can I combine these in a one-liner:

```
> cat file.txt

    bar
    foo
    bar
    baz
    match1
    qux
    blah
    bleep
    match2
    boop
    blah
```

Sample Output for n=2:

```
    bar
    baz
    match1
    qux
    blah
    bleep
    match2
```

Answer (score 1):

Group the commands, that way they share the same input, so when `grep` quits `sed` takes over:

```
{ grep -B2 -m1 match1; sed '/match2/q'; } < infile
```

Answer (score 0):

Try piping the output of the `grep` command to the `sed` command? E.g.,

```
grep <options> file | sed <options>
```

Answer (score 0):

sed is a stream editor. so if you want print previous lines that is already gone you need to keep them in buffer for later use.
so i first keep two lines in the buffer 1{N;N} and maintained with N;D commands

```
sed -rn '1{:X N;N}; 
/match1[^\n]*$/{:Y N; /match2[^\n]*$/{p;n;bX}; bY};
N;D' infile
```